# $f_y(x,y)=0$ has a unique solution for $x$; then $f(x,y+\epsilon)-f(x,y)=0$ has a unique solution for $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

$f(x,y)$ is a smooth function.

The following equation has one single unknown $x$:

$$f_y(x,y)|_{y=a}=0$$

We know that the equation has a unique solution, $x=x^*$.

Is it possible to show that, $\exists\delta\forall |\epsilon| <\delta$, the following equation (2) of $x$ also has a unique solution for $x$?

$$f(x,a+\epsilon)-f(x,a)=0  \ \ \ (2)$$

--

I think we should use basic definition of derivative.

$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{f(x^*,a+\epsilon)-f(x^*,a)}{\epsilon}=f_y(x^*,y)|_{y=a}=0$

However, I am afraid of that we could construct a weird case that there are two solution for $x$.

Comment: At first it seems like the mean value theorem helps but the result it gives you can depend on $x$ as well as $\epsilon$. It might help anyway, at least in the small $\epsilon$ case.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the hint! Of course $\epsilon$ can be really small, as $\delta$ can also be arbitrarily small.

Comment: My hint might not be helpful, I didn't solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counterexample:

Consider the function $f(x,y)=x^2y-\frac{y^3}{3}$. Choose $y=y_0=0$. Then one calculates the quantities for arbitrary $y_0$:

$$f_{y}(x,y)|_{y=y_0}=x^2-y_0^2$$

$$f(x,y_0+\epsilon)-f(x,y)=\epsilon(x^2-y_0^2-\epsilon y_0-\frac{\epsilon^2}{3})$$

Now, it is very easy to see that while the first line when equated to zero has a unique solution for $y_0=0$, namely $x=0$, while the second line, for any arbitrarily small value of $\epsilon$ has 2 solutions, $x=\pm\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{3}}$. Hence no such neighbourhood where the second equation has a unique solution exists.

My intuition is that this could become a theorem if the uniqueness assumption is strengthened to "$\exists~ \epsilon>0~~$ such that$~~f_{y}(x,y)=0~$has a unique solution when inverted for $x$ for $|y-a|<\epsilon$".

Comment: Thank you! I've posted a new questions following your suggestion. In the new question it is required that for all $y$, $f_y(x,y)=0$ has a unique solution when inverted for $x$. I also rule out the case when $x^*$ is a critical point. Is the condition too strong? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451409/for-any-y-f-yx-y-0-has-a-unique-solution-for-x-then-fx-y-epsilon-f

Comment: It seems like that I got a sketch of the proof in the new link