# For any $y$, $f_y(x,y)=0$ has a unique solution for $x$; then $f(x,y+\epsilon)-f(x,y)=0$ has a unique solution for $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

$f(x,y)$ is a smooth function.

The following equation has one single unknown $x$:

$$f_y(x,y)|_{y=y_0}=0 \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

We know that, for each $y_0$, the equation (1) has a unique solution: $x=x^*$. In addition, $f_{xy}(x,y)|_{(x,y)=(x^*,y_0)}\neq 0$.

Is it possible to show that, $\forall y_0\in\mathbb R, \exists\delta>0, \forall |\epsilon| <\delta$, the following equation (2) of $x$ also has a unique solution for $x$?

$$f(x,y_0+\epsilon)-f(x,y_0)=0  \ \ \ (2)$$

---

We should use basic definition of derivative.

$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{f(x^*,y_0+\epsilon)-f(x^*,y_0)}{\epsilon}=f_y(x^*,y)|_{y=y_0}=0$

And also the mean-value theorem. I am thinking hard for more strategies.

I am also trying with Taylor expansion. The equation (2) becomes:

$$f(x,y_0)+\epsilon f_y(x,y_0)+\frac{\epsilon^2f_{yy}(x,y_0)}{2}+...=f(x,y_0)$$

$$0=f_y(x,y_0)+\frac{\epsilon f_{yy}(x,y_0)}{2}+... \ \ \ (3)$$

Since $f$ is smooth, then $f_y(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable in $x$. Since $f_{xy}(x^*,y_0)\neq 0$, through mean-value theorem we can show that $f_y(x,y_0)$ is strictly monotonic in $x$ in a local interval around $x^*$; let's assume this local interval is $I=[x^*-\gamma,x^*+\gamma]$.

Since $I$ is closed, then $f_{yy}(x,y_0)$, when regarded as a function of $x$, must be a BV function on $I$. Since $f_y$ is strictly monotonic in $x$, there exists $\delta>0$ for any positive $\epsilon<\delta$ we have $f_y(x,y_0)+\epsilon f_{yy}(x,y_0/2)+...$ is also strictly monotonic. So now if we can prove that the solution to (3), say $x=x^{**}$, is also in interval $I$, we are done. In fact, since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, $x^{**}$ can be arbitrarily close to $x^*$, and of course in $I$. qed

Do we need to use mean value theorem?

(However, I am still afraid of that we could construct a weird case that there are two solution for $x$. Any comments to pointing out my mistakes are welcome!)

Comment: You can just taylor expand $f(x,y_0+\epsilon) - f(x,y_0)$ as the sum of the derivatives in $y$ evaluated at $(x,y_0)$, which are all zero, thus giving a difference of zero.